# How to sum and subtract char* numbers?

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, char

My problem is that I don't know how to sum huge numbers (like "172839023498234792834798237494" or "-172839023498234792834798237494"). So I made `char* m_value` where I will store this kind of objects. Now what I want to do is making some basic arithmetic operations. Should I first convert it or use some like `itoa` ? In my case there is no other options then char* to store numbers.

**Main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LargeNumber l1;
    LargeNumber l3("172839023498234792834798237494"); 
    LargeNumber l7("-172839023498234792834798237494"); 

    l1 = l3 + l7;  //How to do it ?

    return 0;
}
```

**LargeNumber.h**

```
class LargeNumber{

      public:
      LargeNumber(char* value):m_value(value)
      {}

      LargeNumber operator+(const LargeNumber&);
      private:
      char* m_value;
}
```

**LargeNumber.cpp**

```
LargeNumber LargeNumber ::operator+(const LargeNumber &b)
{
        return LargeNumber ( ... );  //Sum both LargeNumber ???
}
```

Comment: l1 = l3 + l7 should be l1 = l3 + *l7

Comment: Processors can't handle numbers that large. You are going to have to write a fancy algorithm to work on it in smaller pieces and reconstruct it as a char*.

Comment: If you have numbers too big to represent as built-in types (or you are doing this for HW) then you simply implement the old school book by-hand long multipliction/division

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use a large numbers arithmetic library. [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) is a good option. Your processor cannot natively perform operations on numbers of this size, so these libraries take care of all the old-school math for you in software.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the whell, you should use a [BigInteger](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) library.

And anyway, C strings are not the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a string, I'd do it as an array of int (or long).  The algorithms for the operators would be just about what you'd do by hand.

Comment: You are right, but the poster will have to handle numeric overflows. This can get slightly tricky.